# blender 2.8 glRectf() not there

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

I'm trying to convert a 2.79 add-on to 2.80. I'm running into a problem with openGL function glRectf(). The code that's currently in the add-on draws the menu as follows

```
bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
if item['highlighted']:
    bgl.glColor4f(0.555, 0.555, 0.555, 0.8)
else:
    bgl.glColor4f(0.447, 0.447, 0.447, 0.8)

bgl.glRectf(x, y, x + width, y + height)
```

FYI: the original addon is here: https://github.com/BlenderAid/Asset-Flinger

Looks like in the latest OpenGL library blender 2.8 is uing glColor4f() is not there and neither is glRectf().

I'm guessing that I can use glColorBlend() instead of glColor4f(). But I can't figure out how to draw a rectangle without glRectf().

I understand the comment about openGL drawing can no longer use deprecated functions. But I'm wondering if anyone is aware if the API was added. I see that there is an add-on archipack that used to used glRectf(), but now uses another method... been trying to reverse engineer it, but having a difficult time.

any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: well I found these. I think this is the new API
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/gpu.html?highlight=gpu#module-gpu

thanks to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgrgEoNFNsA